# How to hide gridlines in specific cells

Tags: google-sheets

I know it is possible to hide the gridlines in the entire spreadsheet, but I am unable to hide gridlines in two specific cells.

I have tried selecting the two cells then hiding the gridlines, but this still affects the entire sheet.

Here is what I have currently:

> [image]

Here is what I am looking for:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set a border for the wanted lines you want to be hidden
2. Set border color for the same lines to white